# Self-sizing UILabel with UIView Subclassing

Tags: ios, swift, layer

I have a sketch and I'm trying to achieve the concept programmatically.

Here's my Sketch:

[image]

Achievement:
[image]

My code:

```
let luna = UIView()

let descStrWidth = messageDescription.stringWidth  // Using String Extension i made.
let descStrHeight = messageDescription.stringHeight // Using String Extension i made.

let titleStrHeight = messageTitle.stringHeight // ..
let titleStrWidth = messageTitle.stringWidth // .. 


let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = messageTitle
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-demibold", size: 13)
titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // whole idea of self-sizing 

let titleDesc = UILabel()
titleDesc.text = messageDescription
titleDesc.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-regular", size: 9)
titleDesc.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
titleDesc.numberOfLines = 0

// My mainView 

luna.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 40, width: screenWidth - 30, height: titleStrHeight + descStrHeight)
luna.center.x = luna.center.x
luna.backgroundColor = .white
luna.addShadow(radius: 11, opacity: 0.2) // Some Shadow
luna.layer.cornerRadius = 10

titleDesc.frame = CGRect(x: luna.frame.minX + 3, y: titleLabel.frame.maxY + titleStrHeight, width: luna.frame.width, height: descStrHeight)


titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: luna.frame.minX + 3, y: 8, width: titleStrWidth, height: titleStrHeight)

luna.addSubview(titleLabel)
luna.addSubview(titleDesc)
self.view.addSubview(luna)
```

Getting provided string width and height:

```
 extension String {
    var stringWidth: CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.width
    }

    var stringHeight: CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

This is what I achieved so far. This might be easier with constraints, right?

[image: HELP]

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you do not use Autolayout? Because a layout like this could be quite trivial to implement...

Comment: @Alladinian, I know right, the problem is. I don't know AutoLayout. Can you help?

Comment: I agree with @Alladinian, why don't you use autolayout? It would very easy to do this view with it.

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio. I've provided everything in the question. If its easy. I'd really appreciate your time and you'd save days of my coding time. Please. go ahead and write a solution

Comment: I asked you why don't use auto layout to understand if you cannot use it for some reason. Because my answer would use it

Comment: Cant you just use storyboard? Its much easier to learn than use code, many tutorial also? If it has to be programmatically then use some autolayout library, they are also simplified the code a lot

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio, I only do AutoLayout on Storyboard, So yeah. I’d love to take your answer

Comment: @Tj3n. This is a goal I set for my self. So no storyboard

Comment: @KimberlyLife please select best answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution by using auto layout and stack views.

```
let luna = UIView()

let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = "Title"
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-demibold", size: 13)
//titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // whole idea of self-sizing

let titleDesc = UILabel()
titleDesc.text = "Description"
titleDesc.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-regular", size: 9)
//titleDesc.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
titleDesc.numberOfLines = 0

// My mainView

luna.backgroundColor = .white
//luna.addShadow(radius: 11, opacity: 0.2) // Some Shadow
luna.layer.cornerRadius = 10

let verticalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, titleDesc])
verticalStackView.axis = .vertical

let okButton = UIButton()
okButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
okButton.setTitle("Okay", for: .normal)
okButton.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal) // to stretch the okay button horizontally

let horizontalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [verticalStackView, okButton])
horizontalStackView.axis = .horizontal

luna.addSubview(horizontalStackView)
view.addSubview(luna)

horizontalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // when using autolayout from code, this property must be false, otherwise constraint won't work
luna.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// This method activates all constraint (when you create a constraint with anchors, by default they are disabled)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        horizontalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.topAnchor, constant: 8),
        horizontalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
        horizontalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
        horizontalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),

        luna.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30),
        luna.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
        luna.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30)
    ])
```

You can change distances between views by changing `spacing` property of stack view. (i.e. `horizontalStackView.spacing = 16` to put a space of 16 points between the two label and the okay button)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let luna = UIView()

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = "messageTitle"
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-demibold", size: 13)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // whole idea of self-sizing

    let titleDesc = UILabel()
    titleDesc.text = "messageDescriptionmessageDescriptionmessageDescriptionmessageDescriptionmessageDescriptionmessageDescriptionmessageDescriptionvmessageDescriptionmessageDescriptionmessageDescription"
    titleDesc.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-regular", size: 9)
    titleDesc.textColor = UIColor.red
    titleDesc.numberOfLines = 0

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Okay", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)

    luna.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleDesc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(luna)

    luna.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    luna.addSubview(titleLabel)
    luna.addSubview(titleDesc)
    luna.addSubview(btn)
    luna.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    luna.layer.borderWidth = 2
    btn.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: .horizontal)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

          luna.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30),
          luna.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
          luna.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),

          titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.topAnchor, constant: 20),
          titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
          titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),


          titleDesc.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
          titleDesc.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
          titleDesc.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
          titleDesc.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),


          btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.centerYAnchor, constant: 0 ),
          btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),


        ])

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As people are saying I would suggest you look into auto layout for the future but for now this should do what you want:

```
    let luna = UIView()

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = messageTitle
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-demibold", size: 13)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // whole idea of self-sizing

    let titleDesc = UILabel()
    titleDesc.text = messageDescription
    titleDesc.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-regular", size: 9)
    titleDesc.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
    titleDesc.numberOfLines = 0

    // My mainView

    // The margins of the labels inside the luna view.
    let margins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 4, 8, 4)

    // The vertical space between the two labels.
    let labelSpace: CGFloat = 4

    let titleDescSize = titleDesc.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: screenWidth - 30 - margins.left - margins.right, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    let titleLabelSize = titleLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: screenWidth - 30 - margins.left - margins.right, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    luna.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 40, width: screenWidth - 30, height: titleLabelSize.height + titleDescSize.height + margins.top + margins.bottom + labelSpace)
    luna.center.x = luna.center.x
    luna.backgroundColor = .white
    luna.layer.borderWidth = luna.addShadow(radius: 11, opacity: 0.2) // Some Shadow
    luna.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: margins.left, y: margins.top, width: titleLabelSize.width, height: titleLabelSize.height)

    titleDesc.frame = CGRect(x: margins.left, y: titleLabel.frame.origin.y + titleLabel.frame.size.height + labelSpace, width: titleDescSize.width, height: titleDescSize.height)

    luna.addSubview(titleLabel)
    luna.addSubview(titleDesc)
    self.view.addSubview(luna)
```

Note: You don't even need to use you string extension as the `UILabels` are capable of calculating the size they need based on their current settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **avenirnext-demibold** and **avenirnext-regular** custom font. But when you are calculating string width and Height you're using system font **UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)**. You're not getting the correct width and height of the string. titleLabel and titleDesc both labels width should be less then luna width for **Padding**.